# Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody doesn't refresh when updated under inline response

Tags: office365, vsto, outlook-addin, microsoft-teams, mailitem

When setting `MailItem.HTMLBody` for a inline response, sometimes the updated body never gets displayed. If I make a call to `MailItem.Save()`, sometimes it shows up but only under saved draft preview. Does anyone know of a way to force the updated HTMLBody to render?

Some addition findings:

- For emails with only plain text (but `MailItem.BodyFormat` is
  `OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML`), this always happens.
- For emails with HTML content and images, this happens if user chooses to download external content when replying
- **For emails with HTML content and images, this does NOT happen if user chooses not to download external content**

I have tried to use different routes to get the MailItem through the explorer and they all lead to the same results. Here are the different methods I've tried, in case I missed anything:

1. Through Outlook.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer event handler arg
2. Through `ActiveInlineResponse` property

> explorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
>
> response = explorer.ActiveInlineResponse;

3. Through `InvokeMember("ActiveInlineResponse"...`

> explorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
>
> response = explorer.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveInlineResponse",
>   BindingFlags.GetProperty |  BindingFlags.Instance | 
>   BindingFlags.Public,  null, explorer, null) as MailItem;

Environment:

- Office version: 16.0.10827.20118
- Windows 10
- Office 2007 Primary Interop
- VSTO 2010

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I found what causes this behavior. It doesn't fully explain the underlying problem but at least we have a workaround.

Prior to setting HTMLBody, we accessed the document to retrieve selected text through `Document doc = MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor`.

Changing this to `Document doc = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` eliminated the issue described above.