# Refreshing outlook mailitem.display after further applying modifications

Tags: vba, outlook, display, mailitem

Usually modifications to a `mailitem` is performed prior to display. However, special circumstances require a refresh after the `mailitem` is on display in order to accomodate post-display modifications made to it.

I tried putting multiple `mailitem.display` at different locations in my code, but it seems to work unreliably.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest closing the item before changing it, and then re-opening.

Comment: Your solution is indeed a means to an end. However, is there a way to "refresh" the display as the question at hand goes?

Comment: What exactly do you do that requires a refresh?

Comment: Your question is unclear but may be similar this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010824/outlook-mailitem-htmlbody-doesnt-refresh-when-updated-under-inline-response

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.  It seems to have the same effect as opening and closing the message manually and causes Outlook to update the view.  I use this after programmatically removing attachments so that the Outlook view no longer shows an attachment icon next to the message.

```
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Set olInspector = useYourTargetMailItemVariable.GetInspector
    
Dim targetMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Set targetMsg = olInspector.CurrentItem
    
targetMsg.Close olSave
```

Answer (score -1):

You could called EMail Watcher, for example:

```
With oMail
    .To = addr
    .Subject = "CCAT eVSM Utilities License Code"
    .Body = "Message body"
    .Display
End With
Set CurrWatcher = New EmailWatcher
Set CurrWatcher.BoolRange = Range("G12")
Set CurrWatcher.TheMail = oMail
```

For more information, Please refer to this link:

[VBA Outlook Mail .display, recording when/if sent manuall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533066/vba-outlook-mail-display-recording-when-if-sent-manually)